# Not all Post Authors showing in Sidebar

Tags: wordpress

Not all my authors are being displayed in sidebar widget. One in particular has multiple published blog posts.

The problem arisen when a database was backed-up and restored on another server. Both databases, and code should be identical.

Its the standard authors widget that comes with wordpress.

Comment: can you post anymore information? some code maybe?

Comment: i cant. Its just the standard authors widget. Tried google, but wanted to see if there was something I could start looking at. More info added shortly.

Comment: Have you tried removing the widget completely (not saving it in inactive) and then re-adding it?

Comment: @JCL1178 I thought I did, but after reading this I tried it and it worked. Put that in an answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the widget completely (not saving it in inactive) and then re-adding it?